# Compactness of semigroups of one-dimensional diffusions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, semigroups-of-operators

I have a question about semigroups of one-dimensional diffusions.

Let $X$ be the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process on $\mathbb{R}$. The generator is expresses as 
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x\frac{d}{dx}.$$
It is known that the $L^2$ semigroup $\{T_t\}$ of $X$ is a compact operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},m)$, where $m$ is the speed measure of $X$. $\{T_t\}$ is extended to strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $L^{p}(\mathbb{R},m)$, $1\le p<\infty$. Moreover, $\{T_t\}$ becomes a compact operator on $L^{p}(\mathbb{R},m)$ for any $1<p<\infty$. $\{T_t\}$ is **not** a compact operator on $L^{1}(\mathbb{R},m)$.

**My question**

- Is there are nontrivial diffusion on $\mathbb{R}$ whose semigroup is compact on $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ for any $1 \le p \le \infty$? Consider the following differential operator: 
  \begin{equation*}
  \frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^{3}\frac{d}{dx}.
  \end{equation*}
  and the diffusion $Y$ associated with the above operator. The semigroups associated with $Y$ is compact on $L^{p}(\mathbb{R},m)$ for any $1 \le p \le \infty$? Here, $m$ is the speed measure of $Y$.

**Dirichlet form of $Y$**

The Dirichlet form of $Y$ is expresses as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{E}(f,g)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f'g'd\mu,\quad f,\ g \in \mathcal{F}\\
\mathcal{F}&=\{f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu): f' \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}.\mu)\},
\end{align*}
where $d\mu=\exp(-x^4/2)\,dx$ and $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $f'$ is the distributional derivative of $f$.

Comment: What is $m$ for this $Y$ ? And are you sure you mean $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^2\frac{d}{dx}$ rather than $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-|x|x\frac{d}{dx}$ ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. $m$ is the speed measure for $Y$. Also, I changed the definition of generator.

Comment: Concerning your original question "Is there are nontrivial diffusion on ℝ whose semigroup is compact on $L^p(\mathbb R)$ for any $p$?": if you switch to quadratic forms and allow for weighed spaces, then the semigroup on $L^2$ is compact if and only if the form domain is compactly embedded in $L^2$. This will be most likely be related to the weights.

Comment: Please tell me related papers.

Comment: Do you want $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^3\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: No. I want $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^3\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your question consists of two parts? (i) The question for general diffusion semigroups on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and (ii) the particular differential operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} - x^3 \frac{d}{dx}$? Or are you only interested in (ii)?

Comment: Both are concerned, but I am particularly concerned about (ii).

Comment: So $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the Lebesgue measure in (i)? [By the way, if you start a comment with @username, then "username" is informed about your comment by the system; this is especially helpful when you wish to answer a comment of another user.]

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: Thank you for your advice. $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with a Lebesgue measure with density. For $Y$, we consider the measure $\mu$ defined by $d\mu=\exp(-x^4/2)\,dx$.